# find last row values and echo on page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website, you can upload pictures via php/mysgl into a database, and the homepage randomly shows the pictures when you click on them.

When someone uploads a photo I want to be able to redirect to the homepage and spit out a value in the database, instead of showing a random photo, I want to show the photo they uploaded.

So I have something like this...

Database
table name - posts
primary key - ID
var - name
var - location
var - caption
var - imageURL

I understand If/else

I don't understand...

How do I write

mysql_select_db('posts')
find LAST row ID
find the var name in that row/ID
echo out the value inside the row 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select id, name, location, caption, imageUrl from your_tablename order by id desc limit 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['caption'];
    echo $row['imageUrl'];
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! but because I am such a NOOB i really don't understand how to write that correctly. Can you write it with correct syntax, with the echo